# Errors in android app that sends user coordinates into a database

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm creating an android app that sends the user's coordinates into a database. There are no bugs in my code but I get errors when I run it. There is a `GPSTracker` class which gets the latitude and longitude.(No error with that one). The errors I get are:

> `04-08 13:40:27.673 3036-3036/com.example.benoit.test`
>   `W/System.err: com.android.volley.`
>   `TimeoutError 04-08 13:40:27.674 3036-
>       3036/com.example.benoit.test`
>   `W/System.err: at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:122) 
>       04-08 13:40:27.674 3036-3036/com.example.benoit.test`
>   `W/System.err: at 
>       com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)`

**This is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button emgbutton;
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/work/wfile/test.php";

    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        emgbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emergency);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        emgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.bounce);

                // Use bounce interpolator with amplitude 0.2 and frequency 20
                MyBounceInterpolator interpolator = new MyBounceInterpolator(0.2, 20);
                myAnim.setInterpolator(interpolator);
                emgbutton.startAnimation(myAnim);
                GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                if (mGPS.canGetLocation) {
                    mGPS.getLocation();
                    final String ulat =String.valueOf(mGPS.getLatitude());
                    final String ulong =String.valueOf(mGPS.getLongitude());

                    StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                builder.setMessage(response);
                                AlertDialog alertDialog= builder.create();
                                alertDialog.show();
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not send ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                error.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    ){
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String,String> params= new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("ulat",ulat);
                            params.put("ulong",ulong);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addTorequestqueue(stringRequest);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turn on your GPS/Location ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `com.android.volley.TimeoutError` -- your app cannot reach that server.

Comment: how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you have written correct parameters.

   params.put("ulat",ulat);  //this occurs when "ulat" and "ulong" doesn't match
   params.put("ulong",ulong); // with table attribute
2. Connection error. If you're using localhost, check firewall is off. Other one, your internet connection isn't working properly.